# Not able to install SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssms

I want to use SQL in my local machine for learning.

I have downloaded and installed successfully the latest version of SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe ( 15.0.2000.5 )

While I'm trying to install SSMS (18.10) , User Account Control dialogue box appears, I select Yes and nothing happens.

Below is the log file for the same :

> [3E28:3E0C][2021-10-20T18:50:54]i001: Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Chexki\Downloads\DB_Healthcare_Project\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe, cmdline: '' [3E28:3E0C][2021-10-20T18:50:54]e000: Error 0x80040154: Failed to load manifest as XML document. [3E28:3E0C][2021-10-20T18:50:54]e000: Error 0x80040154: Failed to load manifest. [3E28:3E0C][2021-10-20T18:50:54]e000: Error 0x80040154: Failed to initialize core.

I have researched a lot but could not get any possible solution to this.
This is fresh and first time ever mssql installation on my laptop.

It would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was related to windows.

Although, I could not find any robust solution to this, but resetting the windows clean and installing SSMS first before SQLExpress surprisingly worked fine.

---

With my old system, I used to get error while installing google chrome. So my best guess is it was related to some corruption in OS files of system.